# can`t export csv file from submit button

Tags: php, csv

I wrote the csv export via php,it works.

but I can`t use form to pass the value to let the user decide the csv file name.

the following code is html form code,I pass the data to csv.php to handle the csv export.

```
<form method="post" action="csv.php">
    <input type="text" name="csv-file-name">
    <input type="submit" value="export">
</form>
```

and this is the csv.php file code...but it doesn`t work,did I do wrong ?

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

$csv_arr = array();
// csv header text
$csv_arr[] = array('header1', 'header2');

// file name
$filename = $_POST['csv-file-name'].".csv";

// set the header
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '";');
header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');

for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
    $csv_arr[1] = array(
        'test1', 'test2'
    );
}

// export the data
for ($j = 0; $j < count($csv_arr); $j++) {
    if ($j == 0) {
        echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
    }
    echo csvstr($csv_arr[$j]) . PHP_EOL;
}


function csvstr(array $fields): string
{
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
    if (fputcsv($f, $fields) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    rewind($f);
    $csv_line = stream_get_contents($f);
    return rtrim($csv_line);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? Are there errors? Does something happen that's not supposed to? Does something not happen that's supposed to?

Comment: if I request csv.php directly,it can download the csv. but if I enter the form.html to input the file name and pass to csv.php to handle, the csv won`t  be downloaded. sorry my english description is not good.

Answer (score -1):

disable first the `Content-Disposition: attachment` temporarily

you should se the error and i think it is from  `fopen('php://memory', 'r+');` where is this location?

so first question where are getting your data from?

second,

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
$csv_arr[1] = array(
    'test1', 'test2'
    );
}
```

what is the index `1` used for?

you can write a more simple but check this first

also `implode` function can help you to make your code better